# AdMob in all my view controllers?

Tags: iphone, xcode, admob, ads, banner

I have implemented AdMob & everything seems to work,
But i wonderd, how can i put the banner in all of my view controllers?
For now, i have the banner only on the RootViewController.
I have total of 4 view controllers.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

What you want here is a `GADBannerView` singleton of sorts. You can probably create a wrapping class to act as a singleton for your adView, so something like:

```
@interface GADMasterViewController : UIViewController {
  GADBannerView *adBanner_;
  BOOL didCloseWebsiteView_;
  BOOL isLoaded_;
  id currentDelegate_;
}
```

And just make sure that `GADMasterViewController` always returns a singleton:

```
+(GADMasterViewController *)singleton {
  static dispatch_once_t pred;
  static GADMasterViewController *shared;
  // Will only be run once, the first time this is called
  dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
    shared = [[GADMasterViewController alloc] init];
  });
  return shared;
}
```

Have a method which resets the current view controller that's holding on to the adView:

```
-(void)resetAdView:(UIViewController *)rootViewController {
  // Always keep track of currentDelegate for notification forwarding
  currentDelegate_ = rootViewController;

  // Ad already requested, simply add it into the view
  if (isLoaded_) {
    [rootViewController.view addSubview:adBanner_];
  } else {

    adBanner_.delegate = self;
    adBanner_.rootViewController = rootViewController;
    adBanner_.adUnitID = kSampleAdUnitID;

    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    [adBanner_ loadRequest:request];
    [rootViewController.view addSubview:adBanner_];
    isLoaded_ = YES;
  }
}
```

Then displaying your ad is just a matter of:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    shared = [GADMasterViewController singleton];
    [shared resetAdView:self];
}
```

You probably need to set up a delegate to forward notifications as well since the AdMob SDK doesn't act well to delegates changing on it in the middle of a request.

You can find a blog post about this [here](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/04/creating-gadbannerview-singleton-in.html).

Comment: Thanks RajPara, i tried to follow this post yesturday but " i got lost" and didn't succedded to do that :\... new in all this stuff

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about where you got lost? If you have specific questions can definitely try to help you out with them

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how adMob works but like everything else you can create a `BaseViewController` in which you can add your adMob(in the `viewDidLoad` method) and then all the other viewControllers can subClass this `BaseViewController`. just call `[super viewDidLoad];` in the `viewDidLoad` methods of your viewControllers and you will have it...

hoping this sorts your problem... :)

Comment: Thanks Ankit,   
So let me understand...   
If i have this in the viewDidLoad of the RootViewController:   

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0,
                              self.view.frame.size.height,
                              GAD_SIZE_320x50.width,
                              GAD_SIZE_320x50.height);
    
    self.adBanner = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

So how do i write what you've said in every viewDidLoad for every VC?   
Sorry, it just that i'm new in all of this stuff...

Comment: everyViewController will subclass rootViewController and then  just call [super viewDidLoad]; in the viewDidLoad methods of your viewControllers and you will have it...